# Why my function always mistakenly returns a transposed matrix as output?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, apply

I am basically a beginner in R and my question most likely has a very basic answer but after many tries I just can't figure out the reason why my function always returns a transposed output. Any help is much appreciated. I am using the Rstudio IDE, R 4.1.2.

My goal was to **write a function to add two additional columns to any given dataframe, which correspond to mean and maximum of each row, respectively.**

So I created a sample dataframe:

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(11:20)
c <- c(21:30)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Then I wrote the following function:

```
desc_n <- function(x){
  return(cbind(
                mean(x, na.rm=T),
                max(x,na.rm=T))
              )
}
```

After that I use the apply() function to apply my newly defined desc_n function to every row of the df dataframe.

```
n_df <- apply(df, 1, desc_n)
```

However, while the output is correct mathematically, it is transposed. Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
[2,]   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29    30
```

While I expected it to be 10 rows and 2 columns. No matter what I do, the output remains the same. I know how to transpose the output to my preference, but this is mostly a learning example for me.
So I have 2 questions:

1. Why does the desc_n function returns a [2,10] output while I used cbind in it? Shouldn't it return a [10,2] output?
2. Why does changing the cbind in the desc_n function to rbind returns the exact same results?

Again, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is assembled by `apply`, and it's `apply` that shapes the output (using, of course, your `desc_n` function along the way).

From the `?apply` help page:

> If each call to `FUN` returns a vector of length `n`, and `simplify` is `TRUE`, then `apply` returns an array of dimension `c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])`

Whichever way you bind it, your `desc_n` function returns something of length 2, so you get 2 rows in the apply-simplified output.